# select products with no relation to another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables `product_product` and `product_location_stock`.

table `product_product` doesn't have any relation to `product_location_stock`

`product_location_stock` have `product_id` column and it is relation to `product_product`

and my goal is to get ids of all products that do not have `product_location_stock`

there are some products that are assigned to product_location_stock and there is some that are not, so basically I need to get ids of those that not.

so first I thought that I need to get all product_ids like

```
SELECT id FROM product_product
```

and after

```
SELECT product_id from product_loction_stock
```

and maybe then compare id's and get ids that don't match?

and after that I'm kinda stuck, so is it even possible to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NOT EXISTS` is the direct translation of your requirement into SQL:

```
SELECT product_product.id
FROM product_product
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT 1
    FROM product_location_stock
    WHERE product_location_stock.product_id = product_product.id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Below code may help you.

```
SELECT P.product_id  FROM  product_product P
left join product_location_stock PL ON PL.product_id =P.product_id 
WHERE PL.product_id  IS NULL
```

Comment: The disadvantage is that this will calculate *all* matches, while `NOT EXISTS` will stop after finding the first match.